# Am I allowed to post a second, better edition of a challenge?

Tags: discussion, challenges, asking-questions, duplicates

I recently made my first PPCG challenge, [Sign that word!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54945/sign-that-word). Now that various improvements have been suggested by more experienced users of PPCG, I would like to post a second, improved version of the challenge.

Is this allowed (or would it be flagged as a duplicate)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [generally accepted rule](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1876/18487) is:

> Can answers from one question be copied over to the other with little or no modification and still be competitive?

If you are unsure, post your revised challenge in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/18487) and ask if others think it is a duplicate.

Comment: I've looked at the answers to the first one, and I can see that only a couple of the answers will work with the new rule set. Is this OK?

Comment: @Kslkgh the relevant part of the quote is "and still be competitive". Would the two valid answers likely win the new challenge?

Comment: @MartinBüttner No.