# Is this coin flipping challenge really a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

[The challenge in question.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/114520/flip-a-coin-for-me.)

I have discussed this in the comments of the challenge and [in the chat room for that challenge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36392237#36392237) where I was told that TNB was the place to discuss it. [I brought it up in TNB](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36541498#36541498) and I was told to discuss it here.

[This is the current consensus on what on is makes a challenge a duplicate.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/777/are-two-questions-duplicates-if-they-have-different-scoring-rules/)

I also feel that it is worth noting that a total of seven close votes and seven reopen votes were cast for this challenge. It was closed twice by members with ["dupe hammers"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges/89/code-golf) and the two most recent repoen votes have "aged out" and expired.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, they are duplicates

My position on this should be obvious, as I was one of the aforementioned dupe hammers, but I'll spell out my reasoning here for discussion purposes.

The relevant portion of the current consensus is

> "Can answers from one question be copied over to the other with little or no modification and still be competitive?"

From my perspective, a sizable chunk of answers from the **1/N** challenge can be trivially modified to fix the "input" to `2` and still be competitive or reasonably competitive on the **Coin Flip** challenge. Hence, my dupe hammer vote.

Comment: Example of allegedly trivial modification: [this three byte answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/114520/flip-a-coin-for-me/114521#114521) and [this five byte answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66922/1-n-probability/66954#66954) that share one character. [Our previous discussion about this can be found here.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36543418#36543418)

Comment: Some languages might not carry over as well as AdmBorkBork stated, but looking at the other answers, many of them can be carried over with little effort.

Answer (score -1):

## No, they are not duplicates

My position on this should also be obvious, as I voted to re-open the challenge and have linked to two discussions I've had about this.

I would argue that the answers on the coin flipping challenge are not trivial modifications from the 1/N challenge. Looking at the answers to the coin flipping challenge, many of those languages were used in the 1/N challenge and few of those answers are a trivial modification. ([Coin 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114532/41863), [1/N 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66969/41863); [Coin 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114531/41863), [1/N 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66940/41863); [Coin 3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114525/41863), [1/N 3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67058/41863); [Coin 4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114522/41863), [1/N 4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66926/41863); [Coin 5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114524/41863), [1/N 5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66955/41863); [Coin 6](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114521/41863), [1/N 6](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66954/41863); [Coin 7](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114528/41863), [1/N 7](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67001/41863); [Coin 8](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114526/41863), [1/N 8](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67039/41863); [Coin 9](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114523/41863), [1/N 9](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66924/41863)) Many of the answers are very different and required golfing beyond just a hard-coded `2` to be competitive.

From my perspective, the change from taking input and feeding it in to a hard-coded `2` is just as trivial a change as between any two countdown challenges ([1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115436/100-day-countdown) [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115342/cook-me-a-hot-dog) [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/114270/how-much-time-is-remaining)) or between [the vanilla "Hello, World! challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world) and almost any [hello-world](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hello-world) challenge that came before it ([1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/307/obfuscated-hello-world) [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1536/hello-world-0-0) [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18721/hello-world-with-limited-character-repetition)). If this coin flipping challenge is a duplicate, then there are a lot of other "duplicate challenges" on here that need cleaning up. I do not see why this coin-flipping challenge is an exception when all of these other challenges have set a precedent that minor variations in answers are acceptable and in the case of hello world, heavily rewarded.

Comment: "*there are a lot of other "duplicate challenges" on here that need cleaning up*": indubitably.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I don't really think that stuff like what I linked too is a duplicate, but now that we've changed the precedent I guess we should all go vote to close them.