# Is "Polyglot the OEIS!" a dupe of "The versatile integer printer"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicates

The recent question, [Polyglot the OEIS!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/137846/polyglot-the-oeis), has been VTCed as a duplicate of [The versatile integer printer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer?noredirect=1&lq=1), however the community has not reached consensus on whether it is a dupe.

Currently, it has been VTCed by the community, reopened, and is one vote from closing.

The question: **Is it a dupe?**

### Please note that voting on this question does not establish your opinion on whether it is a dupe.

**Please vote on answers instead.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Yes

It's a dupe based on our policy of duplicates: *answers from one are easily copy-pasted and modified from one to another.*

[Here's the relevant policy.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1876/58826)