# Can I repost a challenge with different rules?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

Recently, I posted a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) question about number sequences. However, as I was looking through the question later, I thought to myself, "*Wouldn't this be good as a [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm) question?*" It's not that I regret making it code-golf - I very much like it that way. But I also want to see the differences people would make in the algorithm to make it faster, as they can't use recursion, `filter()`, etc for it would be too slow.

Should I:

A.) Post a separate question with the same body but different tag
B.) Come up with a scoring algorithm in my original question to combine speed with length
C.) Leave it as it is

Comment: Good question. Yes you can. We have a strong consensus [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/777/are-two-questions-duplicates-if-they-have-different-scoring-rules), where this question was asked with a different wording.

Answer (score 3):

Our standard rule is that two challenges are duplicates if answers from one could be reused on the other and still be competitive.

So in this context, we can apply the rule as follows: if the [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) answers are all generally using the fastest algorithm, they'd also be competitive on [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm), and so you couldn't repost the challenge; but if the [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) answers are generally using slow algorithms (due to that being terser), they wouldn't be competitive on a [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm) challenge, and so you can post both challenges alongside each other.